# Maya create meshes with hardened edges

Tags: maya, mesh

I am creating a mesh export/import plugin for Maya.

When I create a mesh with **MFnMesh.create**, the mesh always has softened edges. If I export meshes that have all hardened edges, the results seems like wrong meshes. So I try to do additional "**polySoftEdge**" command, but it takes considerable time for complex meshes. So I want to know the way to create a hardened edges on the stage of creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the mesh you can set the edges in the API using the `SetEdgeSmoothing()` function for every edge followed by a single call to `cleanupEdgeSmoothing()` and then `updateSurface()` to rebuild the mesh with hard edges.

[Relevant Docs](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/class_m_fn_mesh.html#d390e0418a7f9c6ac774666baa93cfe6)

Comment: Your sugestion is useful to solve my problem. I tried to use MItMeshEdge, but the mesh generated by the data from MFnMesh, does not have identical edge orders. So I use the vertex id to find edge id.